# format string is not a string literal in a variadic template function (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have this simple function, in which I get an error:

> format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Werror,-Wformat-security]

I know that I can make a C-style variadic function and use:

```
__attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, x, y)))
```

but I have to keep it in C++ template style.

Are there any workarounds for this problem? I tried:

```
printf("%s", boost::str((boost::format(inputString) % ... % args)).c_str());
```

but it doesn't work the same as `printf()`.
EDIT:
It doesnt work the same because i handles types differently:

```
    uint8_t a = 1;
    printf("%s", boost::str(boost::format("%u") % a ).c_str()); //this wont print anything, because %u doesnt match uint_8t
    printf("%u",a); //this will print 1
```

```
template <typename... Types>
inline static void log(const char* inputString, Types... args)
{
    printf(inputString, args...);
}
```

Comment: If you aren't worried about this potential security issue, then why are you using the switch -Wformat-security. Just don't use that switch.

Comment: What argument did you use? add example of case when it fails

Comment: Can you use `fmt::printf`? https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#printf-formatting

Comment: @john I have this switch in my company's source code and I don't have access to it.

Comment: @ichik The arguments doesnt matter, because it gives warnings in compilation

Comment: @sehe I dont have access to this library

Comment: @PawełRichert Given the constraints you are operating under I don't see any solution. So I guess you must go back to whoever has given you this 'impossible' task and ask what they are prepared to compromise on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that generally good solutions for this problem are the ones written above in comments, but what worked for me with my project constrains was:

```
#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
#endif
template <typename... Types>
void log(const char* inputString, Types... args)
{
    printf(inputString, args...);
}
#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
```